# PDO Prepared statements and booleans

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following is my Code:

```
$updateAct = $db->prepare("UPDATE alarm SET active=:act  WHERE user_id = :uid AND id = :aid");
$updateAct->bindValue("aid", $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$updateAct->bindValue("act", $_POST['active'], PDO::PARAM_BOOL);
$updateAct->bindValue("uid", $_SESSION['login'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$updateAct->execute();
error_log($_POST['active']);
```

With the above code I can set the field `active = :act` only to false. I don't know why but when I check the value afterwards with MySQL Workbench it is always 0.

However when I change the 3rd line to:

```
$updateAct->bindValue("act", $_POST['active'] ? 999 : 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Then I can only set it to 127. This confuses me even more.

What is happening here?

Comment: Post fields are always strings so there's no way `$_POST['active']` is a valid boolean. You need to run it through a `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "active", FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` first

Comment: You should cast `$_POST['active']` from whatever string it is into a boolean before putting it into PDO.

Comment: Or just use `"0"` and `"1"` as values in your HTML form. There's no need to convert to a true boolean. MySQL does not have a true boolean type. `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` are just synonyms of `TINYINT(1)`. Zero is `false`, anything else is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

> Then I can only set it to 127. This confuses me even more.

In MySQL booleans are commonly defined using the TINYINT datatype, which has a maximum value of 127.

Comment: If it's a boolean value in interpretation then the possible values are zero and non-zero, but it doesn't matter how non-zero it is.